# Access javax.security.auth.Subject from javax.portlet.PortletSession, jboss

Tags: java, jboss, liferay, portlet

**Is there any way to access javax.security.auth.Subject from javax.portlet.PortletSession at rendering stage in liferay portlet?**

I've my custom login module defined which is extending com.liferay.portal.security.jaas.ext.jboss.PortalLoginModule. In it, I can access Subject object and can set the principals here. Now I want to access these principal in my portlet under same application deployed in jboss.

I have access over portletSession backed by by PortletSessionImpl from where I can also access HttpSession. And this HttpSession contains subject and further subject containing principals but I'm not finding any api or way to access it.

Any hint clue much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to retrieve Subject.

```
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext;
import java.security.Principal;

Subject currentSubject = (Subject) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");
for (Principal principal : currentSubject.getPrincipals()) {
// You have access to individual Principal
}
```

Working for me :)